# Simulating Dual Diodes

Tags: diodes, simulation, ltspice

I'm trying to simulate the MBRB20H100CTT4G for a flyback converter (it's going to be the rectifier).
However, only ".model" files are supplied (no .subckt), so I'm confused as to how exactly I should model the dual diode.

Here is the model i'm using :

```
.MODEL MBRB20H100CTG d
+IS=2.42014e-05 RS=0.01 N=1.78382 EG=0.753678
+XTI=4 BV=100 IBV=1e-05 CJO=3.72271e-10
+VJ=1.04295 M=0.478361 FC=0.5 TT=0
+KF=0 AF=1
```

Should I put 2 generic diodes using this model in parallel, or only one ?

Comment: .MODEL files can be used by most simulators. Does yours have a schematic front-end?

Comment: I'm using LTSpice, so yes. My question is more if the .model was a model for the whole component, or only one of both diodes integrated inside said component.

Comment: The `.model` refers to only one of the diodes. You can use that with as many diodes as you want (simply rename `D` to that beautiful name). Placing two such diodes in common cathode will result in a model for what you need.

Comment: It's a model for all devices in the schematic that use it.